# How to configure Caddy server for react-router

Tags: react-router, caddy

What kind of Caddyfile configuration do I need to serve a react app (created with create-react-app) with react-router correctly? Basically, `domain.com/app/` (this is the root of the app) should redirect to `index.html`, `domain.com/app/sub` should redirect to `index.html` (routing will be done on frontend by react-router), but then again for example `domain.com/app/manifest.json` should not redirect to anywhere since it's an actual file that needs to be served. Then there's also `domain.com/app/static/` url which should be served as is.

My current Caddyfile:

```
domain.com/app {
        root /server/public/app
        rewrite / {
                to {path} /
        }
}
```

This kind of works, but it also redirects `domain.com/app/manifest.json` and all `domain.com/app/static/` urls too.

How to tell Caddy to look for a file in the path and if it doesn't exist then redirect to the root? The docs imply this is how the rewrite block should work, but there is something wrong in my configuration file because it does not seem to work.

I have tried many examples already but they all also redirect the /static/ folder and manifest.json etc too.

Answer (score 7):

The directive you're looking for is [`try_files`](https://caddyserver.com/docs/caddyfile/directives/try_files).

> Rewrites the request URI path to the first of the listed files which exists in the site root. If no files match, no rewrite is performed.

In your case you need:

```
try_files {path} /index.html
```

Answer (score 1):

This answer worked: https://stackoverflow.com/a/63688826/4615976 
I also wanted to paste my whole configuration of Django + React app in here for future reference:

```
:443 {
    # django container running on the same host
    handle /api/* {
        reverse_proxy localhost:8080
    }
    # static files that django admin uses
    handle_path /django_static/* {
        root * /etc/caddy/html/django_static
        file_server
    }
    # react app 2
    handle_path /back_office/* {
        root * /etc/caddy/html/back_office
        file_server
        try_files {path} /index.html
    }

    # react app 1
    handle /* {
        root * /etc/caddy/html/oa
        file_server
        try_files {path} /index.html
    }

    header {
        # enable HSTS
        Strict-Transport-Security max-age=31536000;
        # disable clients from sniffing the media type
        X-Content-Type-Options nosniff
    }
    log {
        level info
        format console
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe this is working as you expect, i was able to reproduce it, When you visit `domain.com/app/manifest.json` it returns a JSON file

Answer (score 0):

I was just testing how to serve always `index.html` for BrowserRouter to work and ended up with the following Caddyfile:

```
/ {
  tls off
  gzip
  log stdout
  rewrite {
    to {file} index.html
  }
}
```

That way it will always try accessing files (scripts, styles, images...) before falling back to serving `index.html`